# Using Python to replace VBA code "Do Until Dir( ) <> vbNullString"

Tags: python, excel, vba

I'm currently using VBA / PowerShell to do some automation and crosscheck work between different files. Recently I would like to migrate my VBA work to Python but I have difficulties translating below VBA code to Python.

```
Sub Macro1

Dim PreviousDate As Date

PreviousDate = Date - 1
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Do Until Dir("F:\Test Folder\" & Format(PreviousDate, "yyyy") & "\" & Format(PreviousDate, "yyyy") & "-" & Format(PreviousDate, "mm") & "\" & Format(PreviousDate, "yyyymmdd") & "\SDTeam\blmg0006.csv") <> vbNullString
PreviousDate = PreviousDate - 1
Loop

Set closedbook2 = Workbooks.Open(("F:\Test Folder\" & Format(PreviousDate, "yyyy") & "\" & Format(PreviousDate, "yyyy") & "-" & Format(PreviousDate, "mm") & "\" & Format(PreviousDate, "yyyymmdd") & "\SDTeam\blmg0006.csv"))
closedbook2.Sheets("blmg0006").Cells.Copy Destination:=wb.Sheets("Previous").Cells(1, 1)

closedbook2.Close savechanges:=False

End Sub
```

Above VBA code will check whether yesterday's `blmg0006` csv file exists, if not then check the day before yesterday and so on until it gets the file and then crosscheck with today's `blmg0006` csv file

I'm wondering is there any similar method for python to replace above VBA code? And since `PreviousDate = Date - 1` can not be applied in python any options to get previous date (Currently I know using `datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")` to get current date in python)

For above VBA code, to make it look more intuitive the folder path is `F:\Test Folder\2022\2022-08\20220823\SDTeam\blmg0006.csv`

Comment: Once you have a `datetime` object, you can scoot it backwards by subtracting `datetime.timedelta(days=1)`.

Comment: @TimRoberts Hi Tim, thanks for the help! With your reminder I use ```PreviousDate=(datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=2)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")``` this is exactly what I want to get previous date :)